# Association list, Arraylist Java

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, hashmap

I created an association list here:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> PhoneNumber = new HashMap<>(); 

PhoneNumber.put(8559966, "Jill");
PhoneNumber.put(6669999, "James");
PhoneNumber(255666, "Dylan");
```

What I want to do is call this list in a method but I want to only look at the String half, Jill, James and Dylan. I'm lost on how to do this. I know how to call an ArrayList into a method but not how to call a HashMap and how only look at the Strings.

What I want to do is something likes this:

```
public String getJill(ArrayList<Integer> PhoneNumber){
    String h;
    for(int i = 0; i<PhoneNumber.size();; i++){
        if(PhoneNumber.values(i) == "Jill"){
            h = "Jill";
        }
        return h;
    }
}
```

Comment: Representing a phone number as an `int` is a bad idea.  Use a `String` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean `Map.values()` which returns a Collection?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, String> phoneNumber = new HashMap<>();
    phoneNumber.put(8559966, "Jill");
    phoneNumber.put(6669999, "James");
    phoneNumber.put(255666, "Dylan");
    for(String s : phoneNumber.values()) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Output in my case:

```
Jill
Dylan
James
```

Now if you want them in the same order you put them in the `Map` you must use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap`

```
Map<Integer, String> phoneNumber = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Then your output will be:

```
Jill
James
Dylan
```

Comment: Hi I tried this but I'm getting an error on my package line saying "- The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
  required .class files" when I import the HashMap

Comment: I never mentioned `Map.Entry` Is that somewhere else in your code? then you must import it `import java.util.Map.Entry;`

Comment: It's some weird error message I get when I import java.uitl.*; and try to use the HashMap, Map or LinkedHashMap in my main class

Comment: perhaps is the misspelling of the word `util`?

Comment: Oh sorry I spelled it work in my comment but not in my program.